# What's better solution to separate user input by space in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm reading C++ Primer and working on its exercise. It want me to get user's input and separate by space `' '`. So I come up with 2 solution.

**First solution:**

```
vector<string> vector1;
string input;
string temp = ""; // temperary hold each word value in input.

string x1 = "";
char x2 = 'b';

x1 += x2;

cout << x1 << endl;

getline(cin, input);

input += " ";

for (string::size_type index = 0; index != input.size(); index++)
{
    if (!isspace(input[index]))
    {
        temp += input[index];
    }
    else
    {
        if (temp.size() > 0)
        {
            vector1.push_back(temp);
            temp = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Second solution**

```
vector<string> vector1;
string input;
string temp = ""; // temperary hold each word value in input.

string x1 = "";
char x2 = 'b';

x1 += x2;

cout << x1 << endl;

getline(cin, input);

//input += " ";

for (string::size_type index = 0; index != input.size(); index++)
{
    if (!isspace(input[index]))
    {
        temp += input[index];
    }
    else
    {
        if (temp.size() > 0)
        {
            vector1.push_back(temp);
            temp = "";
        }
    }
}

if (!temp.empty())
{
    vector1.push_back(temp);
}
```

The difference between them is first solution is add space to user input while second solution check that I don't add last word or not. I want to know which one is better solution for this problem?

If there're better solutions, please tell me.

Comment: You should add some comments to your code that explain what it's doing.

Comment: Your two solutions are nearly identical ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write this:

```
std::vector<std::string> data;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator< std::string>(std::cin), 
          std::istream_iterator< std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(data));
```

It is almost same as @K-ballo's answer, except that I let `std::copy` read directly from input stream (i.e `std::cin`) rather than from `std::stringstream`.

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/f0Gtc

--

Or you could make use of vector's constructor, avoiding `std::copy` altogether:

```
 std::vector<std::string> data(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
                               std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

And you're done!  Demo : http://www.ideone.com/Szfes

If you find it difficult to read, then use this instead:

```
 std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(std::cin), end;
 std::vector<std::string> data(begin, end);
```

Demo : http://www.ideone.com/PDcud

Comment: I've been doing a lot of programs that read one line at a time lately, and since OP's code also does that, I stayed in that mindset.  Your code is (much) faster if he doesn't care about linebreaks.

Comment: I kinda feel bad that we replaced all his work with a one-liner :(

Answer (score 1):

In C++, reading space-separated values is quite easy, and is built into the language.  I may be wrong, but it looks like you are over-complicating things.

```
std::string line;
if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::vector<std::string> inputs_on_this_line(
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss)
            , std::istream_iterator<std::string>()    );
    //do stuff with the strings on this line.
}
```

Comment: aw, but overcomplifying is such an awesome "word."

Comment: It can be further simplified. See my solution.

Comment: @OP: If you care about newlines, use this idea.  If you want _ALL_ of the input, use Nawaz's version.  His is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily split the input from a stream into string separated values, and insert them into a vector with:

```
string input;

... get the input, perhaps with getline(cin, input); ...

stringstream input_stream( input );
vector<string> vector1;

std::copy(
    (std::istream_iterator< std::string >( input_stream )), std::istream_iterator< std::string >()
  , std::back_inserter( vector1 )
);
```

The `std::istream_iterator< std::string >` pair will iterate over the `input_stream` by extracting an `std::string` at a time (a string is read until a whitespace character is found). `std::back_inserter` will call `push_back` into your `vector` for each of those strings.

Comment: Why do you need `stringstream`? Why can't you read directly from `std::cin` as I did in my solution? Or there is something I'm missing?

Comment: @Nawaz: Because it seems to me that the OP only wants to split a single line from `std::cin`.